# OpenCPU plot layout error

Tags: r, opencpu

I am using OCPU to plot some charts from the SixSigma package. It works fine in RStudio, it works perfect using the Public OCPU server, but when I try to use the same function in a Linux box I've setup installing OCPU 1.4 using apt-get as instructed, the layout gets funny.

Strange thing is that if I execute the SixSigma function straight up, it plots correctly, but if I create a function that executes the package function, then the plot doesn't work.

```
testPlot <- function(){
  require(SixSigma)
  ss.study.ca(ss.data.ca$Volume, rnorm(42, 753, 3),
              LSL = 740, USL = 760, T = 750, alpha = 0.05,
              f.sub = "Winery Project")
}
```

The above function is being executed in the two servers (public and mine) but getting different results.

Here is a fiddle with the test scenario, two plots, same code, but different result, both are executing the same function.

http://jsfiddle.net/rafaturtle/60v3hxa8/

Comment: Do you have the exactly the same version of R and of the packages imported by `SixSigma` in your two servers?

Comment: Thanks for helping me Pascal, I've checked, and the public ocpu built is R 3.1.0 and my server built is R 3.1.2.

Comment: Same version of packages?

Comment: I went through all packages and dependencies. SixSigma package, same version, qcc, same version, lattice - Public at 0.20-30, min at 0.20-31. Grid public at 3.1.3 mine at 3.1.2, ggplot2 public at 1.0.0 mine at 1.0.1. reshape2 same. Mind you I've just updated all packages using rStudio.

Comment: Another detail is that if I run directly the SixSigma function (without using a function to run it), it works perfectly